# ZingChart Preview Position and Coloring

Tags: javascript, zingchart

I am new to Zingchart and I have some Problems with it.

I want an stacked Bar chart with an second Chart (or here an Preview).

1.)I have the Problem the stacking when I set an color for it, I do not see an difference in the Chart - Why?. -( Is it possible to apply an color to every single stack of an bar?)

2.) It´s only possible to zoom if I click on the background, but not on an dataSet. Since I set much data I am not able to zoom. What can I do that I am able to apply an zoom on an Graph full of data?

3.) How to set the position of the Preview/Chart correctly? No matter how I set the preview.position, only the y changes and not the height or x-Value. Which is also stupid since I can´t see the right Handle of the Preview. Also tried to adjust it with margin, but no success either. I want the Preview on top of the big Chart.

Here is what I am playing with: http://jsfiddle.net/z1zwg6ae/1/

```
     "graphset": [{
    "type": "bar",
        "x": "1%",
        "y": "25%",
        "height": "100%",
        "background-color": "#fff",

        "plot": {
        "stacked": true,
            "stack-type": "100%"
    },

        "scale-x": {
        "line-color": "#555",
            "line-width": "4px",

            "zooming": true,
            "guide": {
            "visible": false
        },
            "tick": {
            "line-color": "#333",
        }
    },
        "chart": {
        "position": "0 0"

    },
        "scale-y": {
        "min-value": 0,
            "max-value": 100
    },
        "scroll-x": {
        "bar": {
            "background-color": "#777"
        },
            "handle": {
            "background-color": "#76DF20"
        }
    },
        "zoom": {
        "background-color": "#20DFC6"
    },
        "plot": {
        "line-width": 10,
            "max-trackers": 9999,
            "mode": "normal",
            "js-rule": "myfunc()",
            "shadow": false,
            "marker": {
            "type": "none"
        }
    },
        "preview": {
        "height": 100,
            "position": "200 100",
            "width": "90%"
    },

        "plotarea": {
        "adjust-layout": true,
            "margin-right": 35
    },
        "series": [{
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you chose quite a complex chart from our gallery to test on! Let me show you some examples on a simpler chart.

1. You can set the stacked color by setting backgroundColor on each series object. Within the series object, we can add a hoverState object to control the mouseover color as well.
2. Out of the box zooming can only be controlled by clicking and dragging the background. You can either use the preview window , or hook into the [zoom methods of the api](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/api-methods/#zingchart__exec__api__zoomin) to create functionality to zoom into the chart. . You could use these methods in an external div outside of the library, or listen for a [node_click](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/api-events/#zingchart__events__node_click) event and attach the zoom method onto it to replicate what you are trying to achieve.
3. The positioning of the preview window can be modified using the position and margin attributes within the preview object.

I'm on the ZingChart team, so feel free to reach out with any further questions!

```js
var myConfig = {
  type: "bar",
  plot:{
    stacked:true,
    stackType:"normal" 
  },
  preview : {
    position : "50% 0%",
    margin : "10 50 80 50",
    height: 50
  },
  plotarea : {
    margin : "90 50 50 50"
  },
  scaleX : {
    zooming : true
  },
  scaleY : {
    zooming : true
  },
  series: [
    {
      values :[20,40,25,50,15,45,33,34],
      backgroundColor : "#3386ff",
      hoverState :{
        backgroundColor : "#2c61ad",
      }
    },
    {
      values:[5,30,21,18,59,50,28,33],
      backgroundColor : "#1963bc",
      hoverState :{
        backgroundColor : "#4988e4",
      }
    },
    {
      values:[30,5,18,21,33,41,29,15],
      backgroundColor : "#44d0e9",
      hoverState :{
        backgroundColor : "#a6f1ff",
      }
    }
  ]
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myChart', 
 data : myConfig, 
 height: 400, 
 width: 600 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id='myChart'></div>
 </body>
</html>
```